# 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' on database submission

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I've got a form for people to add themselves to a waitlist. All the form info is properly submitted except the last parameter. It keeps throwing this exception

'comm.Parameters["@DayofWeek"]' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

It's input from a RadioButtonList. 
All the other threads on this topic I could find seemed to be minor syntax errors but after staring at this for the last day I can't see any. But I may need more experienced eyes. Or is the problem with my collection of the radiobuttonlist value in the string?

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Page.IsValid)
            {

                string dayWeek = dayofweek.SelectedValue;

                SqlConnection conn;
                SqlCommand comm;
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HutWaitList"].ConnectionString;
                conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO waitList (FirstName, LastName, Email, StartDate, EndDate, Spaces, DayofWeek) Values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @StartDate, @EndDate, @Spaces, @DayofWeek)",conn); 
                comm.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            comm.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = firstname.Text;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@LastName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            comm.Parameters["@LastName"].Value = lastname.Text;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@Email", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            comm.Parameters["@Email"].Value = email.Text;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date);
            comm.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = DateTime.Parse(startdate.Text).Date;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date);
            comm.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = DateTime.Parse(enddate.Text).Date;

                comm.Parameters.Add("@Spaces", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            comm.Parameters["@Spaces"].Value = numspaces.Text;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@DayofWeek", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            comm.Parameters["@DayofWeek"].Value = dayWeek;



                try
            {
                conn.Open();

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                dbErrorMessage.Text = "There was an error submitting your waitlist information.";
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
           }
        }
```

Comment: did you see what value you are getting for dayWeek while assigning it as parameter, perhaps its to long with trailing spaces or something, can you post the value of dayWeek that's coming from RadioButtonList

Comment: I assume in your waitList table the DayOfWeek column is an NVarChar 50?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm new to C# so haven't picked up the best formatting/practices yet. I cleaned up the code using the "AddWithValue" format and still get the same problem. I've double checked the table and the column is set to the correct type and name. The other strange thing is when I step through the function in the debugger it will often skip that line with the DayofWeek submission and I have to redo it again to even get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add it in one shot?

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@months", nMonths);

You don't need to specify the types as long as the type you pass in is compatible with the type in the database. This will also ease maintenance. You don't have to change your code every time you change the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this counts as an answer since I got this working. Finally just tried 'Rebuild Solution' and it fixed this problem and another one I've been trying to figure out. I'm new to ASP.net and self-taught mostly so I didn't even realize that could be an option or possible solution until I started noticing the Debugger moving my breakpoints around and Rebuilding the solution was listed as possible fix for that.

Answer (score -1):

It will be more efficient and might fix your problem by doing everything on 1 line:

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@DayofWeek", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dayWeek;
```

You can do this for all your parameters and save a lookup after each Add.